# InDesign CS5 save as CS4 file by default

Tags: adobe-cs5

Is it possible to have InDesign CS5 save as a CS4 file by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem before, and from what I found, InDesign CS5 cannot save files directly in CS4 format. If you need to open a CS5 document in CS4, [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6d4da.html) tells you how to save it in a backwards-compatible file. The problem is it's a read-only format (I think), which is frustrating when you need to bounce between different versions.

There might be a third-party utility to do what you want, though, so let's wait and see if anyone else knows about that.

Comment: That's painful as it would need a roll out to happen to everyone at once. Sigh.

Comment: @Kvad: I know, I ran into this same situation, and it was extremely frustrating. Luckily I didn't have to do it on a large scale; I'm really sorry if you do.